# How to get background image by class name in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I want to get the images from Trullia Posts and they all are assigned to div via class name having background-image.
What should I do?

```
.kMqQpn {
    background-image: url(https://www.trulia.com/pictures/thumbs_6/zillowstatic/ISukfi6equ5pf41000000000.jpg);
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-size: contain;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    flex: 1 1 0%;
}
<div class="SlideWrapper__Container-sc-8vknhi-0 ekTitK"><div data-testid="media-carousel-image-0" class="MediaCarouselSlide__MediaCarouselImage-vvght3-0 kMqQpn"></div></div>
```

You can see that inner div is dynamically changed the class name so what's the solution to get background-image.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [css selector](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors):

```
el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.kMqQpn')
print(el.get_attribute("background-image"))
```

Comment: Moshe Slaven Its still not Working

Comment: @Shahid can you share the url?

Comment: https://www.trulia.com/p/ny/bronx/1049-fox-st-3f-bronx-ny-10459--2403413820?mid=0#lil-mediaTab